# How to Count the Number of Lines of an Output?

Tags: shell, command-line, grep

Let say I have the program:

```
Calculate.py
```

Is there a unix command-line that counts the number of lines outputted from my program, Calculate.py?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can pipe the output in to `wc`. You can use the `-l` flag to count lines. Run the program normally and use a pipe to redirect to `wc.`

```
python Calculate.py | wc -l
```

Alternatively, you can redirect the output of your program to a file, say `calc.out`, and run `wc` on that file.

```
python Calculate.py > calc.out
wc -l calc.out
```

Comment: It's little things like this that make piping so damn powerful. We'd do ourselves good to bring this interoperability back to software development, which I suppose is what Functional Programming is all about.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter on the other thand if you just want to pipe the number of lines into another function, you now need to manually parse the output of `wc`. Mercifully this is easy (`cut -f1 -d' '`), but the same isn't true for every command. There's something to be said for the Powershell approach of making the command line primitive an "object", rather than a text stream.

Comment: @shadowtalker I'm not familiar with Powershell but passing `object`s instead of `String`s makes sense. At some point I'd like to dive deep into more command line tooling.

Answer (score 1):

Above communicate (wc -l) will count the empty lines too. so better to use below command which deletes the empty lines and count it

```
python Calculate.py |sed '/^$/d'| awk '{print NR}'| sort -nr| sed -n '1p'
```

Comment: Seriously?  ```sed | awk | sort | sed``` just to count lines?  (1) `sed '/^$/d'` can be collapsed into `grep -v '^$'` or even `grep '.'`.  (2) Then, to count lines, add `-c`, so `python Calculate.py | grep -c '.'`.  (And you don’t even need the quotes around “**`.`**”.)