# Count the number of lines found by grep

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to know how many instances of a pattern are found by grep while looking recursively through a directory structure.  It seems I should be able to pipe the output of grep through something which would count the lines.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to put the answer together with help from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248245/how-to-count-the-number-of-lines-of-an-output).  The program "wc" program counts newlines, words and byte counts.  The "-l" option specifies that the number of lines is desired.  For my application, the following worked nicely to count the number of instances of "somePattern":

```
$grep -r "somePattern" filename | wc -l
```

Comment: There's also `grep -c`, but it doesn't exactly do what you require: "Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file".

Answer (score 2):

At least with GNU tools:

```
grep -rcZ "some_pattern" | awk -F'\0' '{s+=$NF}END{print s}'
```

This is likely superior in speed compared to `wc -l`.

It also works for files with newline in name.

Comment: worked perfectly, but if you're still around, would you mind making it better by explaining step by step what was done there?

Comment: For grep:

-r searches recursively, -Z prints out the output with the filename separated from the number of matching lines with the nul character.  

For awk:

-F '\0' makes the field delimiter the nul character. s+=$NF is the sum of the values of the last field - NF is the number of fields $NF is therefore the last field, and then s is printed when awk runs out of input and the program ends.